# one step checkout Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order::setShippingAddress() must implement interface

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, onestepcheckout, guest-checkout, paypal-payflow-pro

**Hello, when i enable extension onestep chekout i can't checkout for guest. I can checkout order for login customer. But guest customer cannot success order. It’s show success page but not order id and admin panel and database not show order. But in paypal charge credit customer complete. In folder var/report show error.**

```
Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order::setShippingAddress() must implement interface Magento\\Sales\\Api\\Data\\OrderAddressInterface or be null, array given, called in \/home\/rootname\/websitename.com\/app\/code\/Codazon\/OneStepCheckout\/Plugin\/Model\/Checkout\/PaymentInformationManagement.php on line 116 and defined in \/home\/rootname\/websitename.com\/vendor\/magento\/module-sales\/Model\/Order.php:1009\nStack trace:\n#0 \/home\/rootname\/websitename.com\/app\/code\/Codazon\/OneStepCheckout\/Plugin\/Model\/Checkout\/PaymentInformationManagement.php(116): Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order->setShippingAddress(Array)\n#1 \/home\/rootname\/websitename.com\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Codazon\\OneStepCheckout\\Plugin\\Model\\Checkout\\PaymentInformationManagement->aroundPlaceOrder(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteManagement\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), '10625', NULL)\n#2 \/home\/rootname\/websitename.com\/vendor\/magento\/module-braintree\/Plugin\/OrderCancellatio' in '\/home\/rootname\/websitename.com\/vendor\/magento\/module-sales\/Model\/Order.php' on line 1009
```

**And sometime show Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) on**
https://websitename.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/4HbXvlHpJTdCojS4shmej3X9vfvyRSPS/payment-information

Help me please. Please advise me on how to fix it.
Thank you.

Comment: for guest do you submit shipping address also ?

Comment: Check the overridden file for Magento\Sales\Model\Order in your extension and confirm what interface is it implementing ?

Comment: @Asad Ullah not submit shipping Address because one step checkout

Comment: @AsadUllah app/code/Codazon/OneStepCheckout/Plugin/Model/Checkout/PaymentInformationManagement.php